# Infinite redirection on some questions (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I noticed this problem happening when I am not logged in (works fine when logged in)

I was trying to access this question:
[Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

But chrome gives me an error:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Looking at Fiddler, I get a huge amount of 302 redirects to the same page. Here's the headers for one of the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 20:58:43 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 1805
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-ord1724-ORD
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 60
X-Timer: S1466024323.317119,VS0,VE0
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
```

Comment: Seems fixed now

Comment: This error occurred for me too on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73477. I think it's some transient error with Fastly. (but, to note: there is something wrong here, and *this is reproducible*)

Comment: Can't see that happening with either link (in answer and in comment)

Comment: @Oded It seems to work now, but in the header, instead of `X-Cache: HIT` I was getting, I now get: `X-Cache: MISS` no matter how many times I replay the request. Could the problem be happening only when the question is cached (why isn't it cached anymore? Is that normal?)

Comment: @Kevin - you are not an anonymous user, so it won't be cached.

Comment: @Oded: That was as an anonymous user. https://gist.github.com/kevindqc/5b1f6a2c9bb8ade5c825e8222a79a68e

Comment: @Oded If you feel like pulling up traffic logs, this occurred for me (I logged all of it [in the TL](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30390132#30390132)). Note: this only occurred for me when I wasn't logged in.

Comment: @hichris123 - did you try on chrome a few times, then tried wget?

Comment: @Oded Yes. The Chrome ones didn't work, the wget one worked.

Comment: OK, can see that in the logs (I see a *single* redirect for the Chrome requests). So... something between fastly and you at that point went bunk. Also - the wget request appears to have been for the full URL (including the title) and the Chrome ones without the title, @hichris123

Comment: Yeah, that was an artifact of the links I was using, @Oded.

Comment: @hichris123 - we redirect those to the canonical URL (with the title), but a redirect storm isn't expected. But - I don't see that on our end. Again - if not happening anymore, little we can do about it (might have been a hiccup on the fastly side or possibly something to do with the transition).